# Specific case of tensor-hom adjunction

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra

I'm currently working on a project, for which I need various bits of category theory which I've not seen much of before and do not know in detail, so I would like some confirmation (and probable correction) on what I believe so far.

The context of what I care about is (I think) less important than what it leads to, so this is what it comes to:

I have $M$, a $\mathbb{C}$-algebra, $S\subset M$ a subalgebra, and $N$ an $S,S$-bimodule. So then $M\otimes_S N \otimes_S M$ is an $M,M$-bimodule.

Now what I want to know is whether or not it is true (by tensor-hom adjunction) that $$\textrm{Hom}_{M,M}(M\otimes_S N \otimes_S M, M) \cong \textrm{Hom}_{S,M}(N \otimes_S M, \textrm{Hom}_M(M,M))\cong \textrm{Hom}_{S,S}(N, \textrm{Hom}_M (M,\textrm{Hom}_M (M,M)))$$

I hope this is true because in my case, $\textrm{Hom}_M (M,M) \cong M$ so I will get $\textrm{Hom}_{S,S}(N,M)$ which is what I would like to happen!

Comment: Yes it is true. Note that you can define directly the isomorphism $Hom_{M,M}(M\otimes_S N\otimes_S M,M)\rightarrow Hom_{S,S}(N,M)$. It is the map $f\mapsto (n\mapsto 1\otimes f(n)\otimes 1)$. Its inverse is the map $g\mapsto (m\otimes n\otimes m'\mapsto mf(n)m')$.

Comment: @user113969 Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please don't write answers as comments. This is not how the system is supposed to work here.